# ethernet drivers not working on linaro version 3.1

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Hi all
I am booting pandaboard with Linux linaro version 3.1.
Everything boots fine but Ethernet is not working.
How can I solve this?

When I boot here are some of the outputs so that we can explain the situation much better.

```
#lsmod
no modules are enabled.

#/etc/init.d/networking eth0
device eth0 not found
failed ro bring up eth0.

#ls /sys/class/net/
there is only lo but there is no eth0.
```

So this clearly shows that ethernet drivers are not being enabled.
Is there any chance that I can over come this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the ethernet device?
2. Do you have the driver built into your kernel? (look in `.config`)